# Ionic App showing white Screen after Splash screen

Tags: cordova, ionic4

My application is showing white screen for 3 to 4 seconds after splash screen. I have configured these properties in my ionic 4 project which is given below but it could not solve my issue.

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="8000" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

I have given below my package.json file. please see it carefully and help me to slove it

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite-porter": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^5.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/wheel-selector": "^5.1.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "2.7.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "3.1.0",
    "cordova-wheel-selector-plugin": "1.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "highcharts": "^6.2.0",
    "plotly": "^1.0.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter": "1.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.4.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.21",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-wheel-selector-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help me i am stuck in this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

change like that

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
```